# Adding tabpage to a tabcontrol which is on another form on click of button

Tags: winforms

I have a winform called form1 which has tabcontrol with some tabpages and one button on clicking of which I open another form called form2. I want to add tabpage to form1 tabcontrol on click of button which is present on form2.

Comment: Hi Dinesh, can you please provide any code etc. that you have tried so far? what problems have you faced? Take a look at our quick guide on asking good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumed that you have not created a tabcontrol at runtime in the Firstform.

In FirstForm.cs

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SecondForm obj = new SecondForm(this);
        obj.Show();
    }

    public void addTabpage()
    {
        TabPage tbpg = new TabPage();
        tbpg.Text = "New tabpage";
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tbpg);

        this.BringToFront();
    }
```

In SecondForm.cs, change the constructor as follows

```
    static FirstForm objpub;
    public SecondForm(FirstForm obj)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        objpub = obj;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (objpub != null)
        {
            objpub.addTabpage();
        }

    }
```

If this answer does not meet your problem, then provide your code. 
Cheers !